# Understanding meaning of syntax of git push

Tags: git

**Situation**

1. I have 2 local branches A and B.
2. I have 2 remote branches C and D.
3. The name of my remote is origin.
4. If I want to push changes from my branch B to remote branch D, what should be the git push syntax? I am confused among the following options

- git push origin B:D
- git push origin B/D
- git push origin B
- git push origin D

Please help me in understanding the correct git push syntax as well as its meaning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technical description for this syntax is in the Git manual under ["The Refspec"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) and [the argument description of `git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203), but the short version is that there are two common formats:

- A pair of branch names in the form `source:destination`, e.g. `git push origin B:D` means "source is the local branch `B`; destination is the remote branch `D`".
- A single branch name, which is (unless configured specially) shorthand for `source` and `destination` having the same name, e.g. `git push origin B` is the same as `git push origin B:B`, and means "source is the local branch `B`; destination is the remote branch `B`".

Specifying `B/D` would look for a branch with that name, e.g. some projects have naming conventions like "username/task-number"). However, you may be confusing it with "remote tracking branches", which take the form "remote-name/remote-branch-name", such as "origin/D"; you wouldn't normally be using those in a `git push` command.

Comment: Possible edit - git push origin B is the same as git push origin B:B. I think you missed one origin

Comment: @DawsonSmith Thanks, I missed "origin" from all the commands initially, and realised when I glanced back. They should all be there now.

Comment: Great answer btw. Thanks